# asp.net MVC3 Image breaks on Edit/Create pages, OK on Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a _Layout.cshtml page which I've used to include all "master page" styling. This page includes an image in my header which is mapped in the layout page as:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/Logo.jpg"/>
```

When I created the controllers, I selected the option to create a "controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework" which generated my Edit, Delete, Create and Index views.

My image appears normally on the Index pages for all of my various controllers, however when I click on any of the the Edit, Create or Delete pages, the image breaks. Do I need to map the image differently on these pages, and if so, how do I change this? I was under the impression that all pages pulled content from the layout page the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping the image like so:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Logo.jpg")" />
```